# How to configure webmachine to send crashes to lager, instead of only returning them via http?

Tags: erlang, webmachine

By default, if a webmachine handler crashes, the crash stack trace is returned in the body of the 500 error response.
Is there a way to configure it to log to lager (or some other logging system)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this two documentation sections might be useful for you:

- [log handlers configuration](https://github.com/basho/webmachine/wiki/Logging)
- [error handlers configuration](https://github.com/basho/webmachine/wiki/Configuration#error-handler)